# How to know the incoming byte data is of which protobuf type and how to deserialize it

Tags: python, deserialization, protocol-buffers

I have a stream of data coming onto kafka topic and this data is serialized into protobuf. This topic contains different types of protobuf messages. And I have no idea how it is serialized. But I have all the proto files.

I came to know that this can solve this issue if we have different types of protobuff messages coming onto the topic:

```
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#any
```

I tried to create a simple python code using which I want to wrap the message in ANY object and after that I want to deserialize the data as well.
Below is the sample code:

```
import todolist_pb2 as TodoList
import traceback
from google.protobuf.any_pb2 import Any
from google.protobuf.internal import any_test_pb2
from google.protobuf import map_unittest_pb2
from google.protobuf import unittest_pb2
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToDict


my_list = TodoList.TodoList()
my_list.owner_id = 1234
my_list.owner_name = "Tim"

first_item = my_list.todos.add()
first_item.state = TodoList.TaskState.Value("TASK_DONE")
first_item.task = "Test ProtoBuf for Python"
first_item.due_date = "31.10.2019"

test_any = Any()
test_any.Pack(my_list)
byte_data=test_any.SerializeToString()
print(byte_data)
```

Deserialize

```
deserialize_any = Any()
data = deserialize_any.ParseFromString(byte_data)
print(data)

print(TodoList.DESCRIPTOR.name)
print(test_any.ListFields())


try:
    print("executing if statement")
    if deserialize_any.Is(TodoList.TodoList().DESCRIPTOR):
        TodoList = deserialize_any.Unpack(TodoList.TodoList())
 
        print(TodoList.ParseFromString(byte_data))
    else:
        print("nothing matched")
except:
    print(f"Error while deserializing the data:  {traceback.print_exc()}")
```

I am able to serialize the data but while unpacking and deserializing I am getting below error:

```
b'\n&type.googleapis.com/protoblog.TodoList\x122\x08\xd2\t\x12\x03Tim"(\x08\x04\x12\x18Test ProtoBuf for Python\x1a\n31.10.2019'
92
todolist.proto
[(<google.protobuf.descriptor.FieldDescriptor object at 0x7f3575fcf5e0>, 
'type.googleapis.com/protoblog.TodoList'), 
(<google.protobuf.descriptor.FieldDescriptor object at 0x7f3575fcf730>, 
b'\x08\xd2\t\x12\x03Tim"(\x08\x04\x12\x18Test ProtoBuf for 
Python\x1a\n31.10.2019')]

<class 'bool'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "any_test.py", line 43, in <module>
    print(TodoList.ParseFromString(byte_data))
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'ParseFromString'
Error while deserializing the data:  None
```

Also find below the sample proto file.

```
syntax = "proto3";

// Not necessary for Python but should still be declared to avoid name collisions 
// in the Protocol Buffers namespace and non-Python languages
package protoblog;
import "google/protobuf/any.proto";


// Style guide prefers prefixing enum values instead of surrounding
// with an enclosing message
enum TaskState {
    TASK_OPEN = 0;
    TASK_IN_PROGRESS = 1;
    TASK_POST_PONED = 2;
    TASK_CLOSED = 3;
    TASK_DONE = 4;
}

message TodoList {
    int32 owner_id = 1;
    string owner_name = 2;
    string place_new = 3;

    message ListItems {
        TaskState state = 1;
        string task = 2;
        string due_date = 3;
    }

    repeated ListItems todos = 4;
}
```

I already created **todolist_pb2.py** file using protoc compiler.

Can share the steps how can I deserialize the data? As said I am getting different messages on a kafka topic and I need to deserialize them. I have all the proto file with me.

Comment: Did you read this? https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/blob/master/examples/protobuf_consumer.py

Comment: This is not working as it is giving me the error as: 
"This message was not produced with a Confluent Schema Registry serializer"
It requires data to be serialized using confluent schema registry serializer. And this is the only catch I don't have any idea how data is serialized.

Comment: Okay, then the producer isn't using Confluent library... Your code shows `SerializeToString` function. What do you mean, you don't have any idea? You've not shown any Kafka code here, either to reproduce as a [mcve]

Comment: The code that I have shown is just for testing purpose. I tried to use Any class to deserialize but for that I need to serialize. So I wrote a sample code for serializing and then to deserialize. I thought once data is deserialized using sample message I will replicate same for messages that I am getting from kafka. Actually kafka producer is running in client environment and we don't have access to that.  Proto files were shared. Now I have to deserialize the data.

Comment: As stated, without knowing how data is serialized, it's hard to provide more details regarding Kafka itself.  The Confluent code also produces data "as Protobuf", so simply being told that doesn't help because Confluent uses a slightly different format _along with the Protobuf data_.  Your error - `AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'ParseFromString` is saying that your `TodoList` object in the print line is actually a boolean type, which was the result from `deserialize_any.Unpack` function. In other words, you've overwritten the TodoList class type/import